# Object are showing black in material view

Tags: materials

I just successfully rendered [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ay7fgeQC1WI) clock tutorial. However all of the objects show black in material view. I've been searching online for an hour, found a lot of similar posts but none of the answers match my setup. I have out put nodes, im not in local view, and the light source's specular and diffuse options are checked. Can any one help point me in the right direction?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGhO0.jpg)

([Link to my blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DkkrX3nKSqVk9CWTdLTzNPb2M/view?usp=sharing))

Update:  I've been using my laptop for this project - a dell Inspiron - and recently opened the project on my main pc and selected my nvidia gpu for the hardware. For whatever reason the materials show fine. I think its related to the Intel Intgrated HD graphics on my laptop. Must be some kind of driver glitch. The bottom line seems to be that my laptop's integrated graphics don't work well with this aspect of Blender. Thanks for all the help though.

Comment: The file works fine for me. The only way I can get material view to be black is to change the renderer to 'Blender Render' instead of 'Cycles', but the file is already set to 'Cycles' when I open it.

Comment: In material view, you won't be able to see reflections to make the objects shiny. You've set up the glossy materials to be dark gray and that is how they are being displayed on material view:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/v23WE.png

Comment: I actually can't see any material. http://imgur.com/a/sPAxR

Comment: What kind of graphics card are you using?

Comment: I agree with cegaton. Are you trying to use the GPU for the live render? It could be something like being out of ram or having bad drivers. Try it with the cpu.

Comment: @Bob please write an answer so other people can learn from your experience.

Answer (score -1):

You may have a flipped normals. If you swap into edit mode and select one of its faces then ctrl-F to get your drop down and select "flip normal" may help.

Comment: In this case the normals are correct. Plus, the issue is not present opening the file in other systems...

Comment: Ah I see, I figured it wouldn't be as simple as that, but Occam's razor and all...when i get back to my desk Ill take a look at the file itself as i answered via mobile and didn't check the actual file.